# IBM App Connect Enterprise - Remove a default Header using ESQL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have a simple REST API project built using IBM App Connect Enterprise version 11. What I observed is in the response headers, key value pair of **Server** and **IBM App Connect Enterprise** are added by default.

I checked in the server.conf.yaml and couldn't find a place where this is being added.

Is there a way I can remove this header using ESQL, without using a HTTPHeader node.

Will be pleased with any suggestions/help.

Thanks in advance,
Yasothar

[image: Postman response headers]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this done by doing the following.

[image: REST API project main flow]

Since mine is a REST API project, in the main flow, I removed the tick in **Generate default HTTP headers from reply or response** check box. This removed the default **Server** header and also the **Date** header. Hope this helps anyone.